# Reading from UDP socket over WiFi always timeout

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a piece of code that send a UDP broadcast to scan for device on our local network. It works fine when im plugged via ethernet, but it doesnt when im connected via WiFi.

Is there something different to do to connect in UDP when using WiFi?

You can find the code im using below. When using WiFi, `select` always return 0

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;

//Create socket
if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
{
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

/* set up destination address */
memset((char *)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(48620);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.3.255");

//TRYING TO BIND, NOT WORKING
if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
{
    int a = WSAGetLastError(); //ERROR 10049
    perror("bind"); //Says NO ERROR
  }


//allow broadcast
int broadcast = 1;
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) == -1)
    exit(1);


    if (sendto(fd, (const char *)&request, sizeof(request), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("sendto");
        exit(1);
    }

    do
    {
        FD_ZERO(&rdFs);
        FD_SET(fd, &rdFs);
        lTimeout.tv_sec = 1;
        lTimeout.tv_usec = 000000;
        lSelRet = select(fd, (fd_set*)&rdFs, NULL, NULL, &lTimeout);
        if (lSelRet > 0 && FD_ISSET(fd, &rdFs))
        {
            addrFromSize = sizeof(addrFrom);
            lResult = recvfrom(fd, bufferIn, sizeof(bufferIn), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addrFrom, &addrFromSize);
            //Treat result
        }
    } while (lSelRet > 0);
```

Note : Even using WiFi, i can estalbish a TCP connection and communicate with the device, its just the UDP broadcast that doesnt work

Note2: currently testing on windows, but I will port it to Linux after

Edit : added the SO_BROADCAST as advised by Remy

Comment: WiFi vs Ethernet makes no difference. They are just different types of connections to the same network. The OS handles any differences for you. That being said, the value of the first parameter you are passing to `select()` is wrong, it needs to be `fd+1` instead (unless you are running on Windows, in which case the parameter is simply ignored). Also, you need to enable the socket's `SO_BROADCAST` option using `setsockopt()` before you can then send or receive packets using an IPv4 broadcast address.

Comment: Thats what I thought about WiFi vs ethernet, but one is working, and not the other. I'll try the SO_BROADCAST and keep you posted

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added the SO_BROADCAST (not sure if im using t right, see edited code), but I think the issue is somewhere else. If I start my code with ethernet plugged in, and unplug it, the code keeps working using the WiFi. And it is still not working if I start with ethernet unplugged

Comment: Change `broadcast` to `int` and use a typecast when passing it to `setsockopt()`: `int broadcast = 1; setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&broadcast, sizeof(broadcast))`

Comment: `setsockopt()` takes a `char*` pointer on most platforms, but that does not mean the data needs to be an actual `char`. Most socket options are integers or structs. Just use a type-cast when passing the pointers to `setsockopt()`.

Comment: Ok, done, still the same behavior

Comment: You are not explicitly binding your socket to a specific adapter and/or port. Sending a broadcast does not usually require binding (unless you need to broadcast to a specific network in a multi-homed PC), but receiving data usually does. In UDP, `sendto()` will bind implicitly if `setsockopt()` was previous used (which is the case in your example), but maybe it binds to a different port than your receiver is sending responses back to? Hard to say since you have not provided any information about the broadcast received, or what the network traffic looks like in both directions.

Comment: Otherwise, you might need to use a promiscuous capture using `WSAIoctl(SIO_RCVALL)` on Windows (not sure the Linux equivalent), and `WSARecvMsg()`/`recvmsg()` instead of `recvfrom()` if you need to know which adapter receives each packet.

Comment: Not sure how to use these functions, especially WSAIoctl with the option SIO_RCVALL requires a SOCK_RAW, and I use a SOCK_DGRAM

Comment: Furthermore, the issue seems to come from the socket function, because if I enter my `while` loop with ethernet plugged in, and then unplug ethernet, it works fine with the WiFi. I've tried to use the bind function, but it fails with the error code 10047 (Address family not supported by protocol family)

Comment: Havent changed anything, but now its error 10049 Cannot assign requested address.

Comment: This is likely a routing issue within your WAP, which is probably blocking broadcast over wifi to preserve wifi bandwidth. I recommend you take this question to http://superuser.com/.

Comment: @DavidLevy you are trying to bind to the broadcast IP, which is wrong. When binding to an IP, it must be an IP that belongs to a local adapter, then subsequent reads/writes will use that specific adapter. If you don't want to bind to a specific IP, bind to `INADDR_ANY` instead. On Linux, you can then use `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE)` instead if needed (does not exist on Windows).

Comment: If I bind to INADDR_ANY, I indeed receive data from network, but still nothing from my scanned devices. As CAB said, its likely related to WiFi management. I asked on superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working, it was a code issue, not a router issue.

The issue was a misuse of the bind function, I needed to use my IP and not the broadcast IP.

```
/* set up destination address */
memset((char *)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(48620);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.3.134");   //<== Windows : My IP, not the broadcast IP
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Linux

if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
{
    perror("bind");
}
```

EDIT : strangely enough, in windows you must bind to the ip sending the request, and on linux you must bind to INADDR_ANY.